# Applescript assign placeholder text

Tags: applescript, placeholder

In xcode you can fill in a placeholder text to a input field in the MainMenu.xib but is it possible to assign the text from the AppDelegate.applescript file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming textField is a connected IBOUTLET

```
textField's setStringValue_(missing value)
textField's setPlaceholderString_("someText")
```

It's important to nil the string Value or set it to empty "" to show the placeholder text.

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Check what? If the value is empty? Log it: log textField's stringValue() or compare it: if (textField's stringValue() is missing value) then...